# What is the meaning of 쥐쥐?

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang

A friend send me this text:

> 그러면 그 뒤로 갈까요? 아니면 오늘은 쥐쥐?ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ

What is the meaning of 쥐쥐 here and how is the expression derived? I assume it means to cancel?

Comment: 쥐쥐는 스타크래프트에서 전세가 불리하던 선수들이 게임을 포기할때 사용하던 gg(good game)에서 유래된 말이지만 게임을 포기할때 썼기때문에 사람들 사이에서는 본래 뜻과 달리 취소하다, 포기하다 라는 뜻으로 주로 쓰입니다. 그리 널리쓰이는 용어는 아닙니다. 20~30대 계층의 사람들은 대부분 무슨말인지 알고 있을 겁니다.

Comment: @SIS 감사합니다! 설명이 아주 좋았어요.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A gaming term: GG <sub>good game ― `gg`, `ㅈㅈ`, `지지`, or `쥐쥐`.</sub>

[image: GG in Starcraft]
[image: GG in CS: GO]

- [Know Your Meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/gg)

> The acronym was referenced online as early as October 1999 in an article on the *Internet Chess Club* website about gaming etiquette. The author explains that receiving a “GG” when playing chess can be a touchy subject because chess players are often sore losers. …
>
> Due to its particular association with international *Starcraft* gamers, the term has gained a significant level of recognition outside the English-speaking web as well, most notably among South Korea's professional gamers who have taken the acronym as an obligatory closing statement to be issued by the defeated player.

- [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GG)

> A polite remark uttered after the end of a round, game, or other measured interval to indicate that a match was fair and enjoyable.

- [Namu wiki](https://namu.wiki/w/GG)

> Good Game의 약자로 원래는 멀티플레이 게임에서 패배를 인정하고 포기할 때 "It was a Good Game"(좋은 게임이었습니다)의 의미로 인사말처럼 쓰는 말이었는데, 게임을 끝낼 때 패자가 패배 선언의 의미로 먼저 쓰는 게 관례가 되다 보니 후에 게임 포기 내지는 패배 선언으로 그 의미가 바뀌었다. …
>
> 국내의 인터넷에서는 아무리 뭘 해도 답이 없어서 포기할 때 쓰이며, 동의어로 지지, ㅈㅈ가 있다. 스타리그의 영향력이 약해진 최근에는 해외 유저들의 용례를 그대로 받아들여 게임이 끝난 후 'ㅅㄱㅇ' 정도의 뉘앙스로 주고받는 경우도 늘고 있다.

---

**It's not really a Korean term.** Though Korean people, especially Millennials, have used it *a lot* for over a decade that they are so familiar with that term. (Well, except for those never play computer games.)

### Yet another internet history: how Korea got `GG`.

[image: Starcraft logo]

This term came from overseas and got spread throughout Korea via [*Blizzard Battle.net*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle.net), which is an internet-based online gaming, social networking, digital distribution, and digital rights management platform developed by *Blizzard Entertainment*, when it wasn't used to English slangs, when the *Starcraft* boom took over the entire Korea, in the year of 2000.

In *Starcraft*, the only case that a match automatically ended was when every building of a player got destroyed so that he had nothing to do further, which made the match unnecessarily longer. So when a player got outmatched by another player and gave his opponent a virtual victory, he had to type “`GG`” in the chat first to express his intent of surrender and let the match end.

Hence comes “`GG`” meaning *to surrender, to stop doing something (usually because it's hard to handle anymore)*.

> 그러면 그 뒤로 갈까요? 아니면 오늘은 **쥐쥐**? ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ
>
> So, shall we go to the next? Or **GG** now for today? Ahaha.
>
> So, are we going to have the afterparty? Or, are we **done** here for today? Haha.

---

### Its usages in gaming (in nowadays Korea)

Well, using “`GG`” to mean to surrender is still valid, however, it's just that Korean people especially went with the partial meaning of “`GG`.”

“`GG`” is literally an abbreviation for “It was a good game.”, which is something you might want to say when your game comes to an end. It is also used during the game when one thinks that the game's going to end soon, by either his confident (or overweening) victory or his clear loss (This is where the GG meaning to surrender came from.). It may sound polite or toxic depends on the situation.

As the fame of *Starcraft* fades out and the internationalization of the gaming culture arises, Korean gamers also got those meanings and use it often in games as usual.

- (During the game; surrender.) “Ugh, I surrender. Let's end up this game.”
- (During the game; clear loss.) “Okay, okay. I'm going to lose.”
- (During the game; likely victory.) “Hahaha, you see, I will be the victory.”
- (The game ended; polite.) “It was a nice game. Thank you for playing with me.”
- (The game ended; toxic.) “You got completely defeated by me! You suck at this game!”

[image: “GG” in a sorrow]
[image: “GG EZ”]
[image: An offensive “GG”]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the person is saying GG, which, as you may know, means good game.

GG is often typed or said after a PvP (player vs player, as opposed to computers) from one player to another.

Online gaming has become so prevalent in Korean culture that such vernacular spilled out into the world outside the gaming to mean "good bye".